# Driving with old fuel?

Tags: fuel-system

I haven't used my car in a while. The last time I refueled was back in December. I've used it a couple of times but nothing very significant, so I have over 30% of a tank left.

Yesterday I drove it "hard" (kept it for a few minutes at 6K RPM, 120kph in third gear), and then drove around for 1 hour on the highway.

The gauge didn't even move. It's a 1.6L engine, car weighs barely 1000kg, so it's quite fuel efficient.

I did not notice anything strange while driving it. It didn't knock, didn't misfire, it was as "powerful" as I remember.

Should I be worried about this fuel?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Refuel to a full tank and call it a day. If you were going to see issues with the fuel, you would have already seen them. If the vehicle is going to sit for a while, the best thing you can do for it is keep a full tank. This gives less atmosphere for ethanol rich fuel to draw moisture from. If you *know* you're going to leave it sit for a while, put some fuel preservative in it, like Sta-Bil (no affiliation). It will keep the fuel in good standing for up to two years.

Comment: thank you. I didn't know this kind of product existed. I'll investigate!

Comment: In high humidity Florida, USA, fuel stabilizer allowed my 3 year idle generator to start on the third pull. Definitely recommend any brand of this product.

Comment: @fred_dot_u - I'd assume it actually works longer than the two years they put on the bottle, but those be the directions. I have no problems using it in my small engine equipment, either. My vehicles usually don't sit for a long period of time, so I don't worry too much about them, but if I did, I'd not worry about using it there, either.

Comment: How is sit for a while defined? >6 months?

Comment: @findwindow - That's a personal judgement call, but IMHO if you aren't topping off your tank at least once a week, I'd be using some kind of fuel stabilizer.

Comment: @findwindow - I may be a bit over cautious, however, the water in the fuel system which ethanol laced fuel can attract, can cause all kinds of issues besides just poor running. It can rust fuel lines if they are steel. It can clog up filters and injectors. Just lots of down sides to it. Not something I'd like to deal with.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 This is only applicable with a less than full tank yes? At what percentage would you say to top it off?

Comment: @findwindow - If it's going to sit around a lot, keep it topped off. I keep mine filled on a weekly basis.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 your cars are very lucky to have you.